# VB.NET: question about "using" block

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, using-statement

Consider the code:

```
On Error Goto ErrorHandler

Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(OpenFile)
    str = sr.ReadToEnd
    sr.Close()
End Using

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
```

If there is an error inside the `Using` block how do you clean up the `sr` object?

The `sr` object is not in scope in `ErrHandler` so sr.Close() cannot be called.  Does the `Using` block cleanup any resources automatically even if there is an error?

Comment: It seems like you are missing the point of the `Using` block...

Comment: @Dan: I understand that the variable of the using block will only be in scope for the using block, I just wasn't sure how much cleaning up would be done and whether Close() would be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the using block will automatically call `IDisposable.Dispose` (which, for a `StreamReader` is the same as calling `Close`) so there's nothing you need to do (that's the whole *point* of using blocks!)

Comment: what if there is an error during the Using block?  Will it still call Close()?

Comment: Yes, that's what the using block's purpose is. Whenever program execution leaves the block, it will call Dispose.

Answer (score 4):

As codeka says, you don't need to call `Close` on sr. It'll called automatically, and that includes if there is an error. Using the `using` statement gives you the same functionality as `try ... finally ... end try`.

And as you see in the answers to your other question, you shouldn't be using `On Error` etc just do:

```
Try
  Using sr as StreamReader ...
     ...
  End Using
Catch ex as SomeException
...
End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(OpenFile)
    str = sr.ReadToEnd
    sr.Close()
End Using
```

Is really equivalent to this:

```
Dim sr As StreamReader = Nothing
Try
    sr = New StreamReader(OpenFile)
    sr.Close() ' notice: unnecessary '
Finally
    sr.Close()
End Try
```

Keep in mind that code within a `Finally` block will **always execute** before the method returns (if it throws an exception of its own, well, then you're in for a world of hurt). So the `sr.Close` line you have within your `Using` block is superfluous (notice it is unnecessary in the equivalent code using `Try`/`Finally` since `sr.Close` will be called in the `Finally` no matter what -- exception thrown or not).

Comment: Doesn't it call Dispose(), which in turn calls Close()?

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Yes, I believe so. It's been a while so I don't remember if I knew that at the time I wrote this answer or not! I think I did, and just felt like it was a rather minor detail. The accepted answer appears to state it explicitly.